# What is happening when an Elixir module defines `@callback` and also implements the specified function

Tags: elixir

For example:

```
defmodule Demo.Validators.AddressValidator do
  @callback validation_level() :: String.t
  @callback set_validation_level(String.t) :: :ok
  @callback validate(String.t) :: boolean

  def validation_level() do
    Application.get_env(:demo, :validation_level)
  end

  def set_validation_level(level) do
    Application.put_env(:demo, :validation_level, level)
  end

  def validate(address) do
    emit_event("address_validated")

    address
    |> String.length()
    |> validate_length()
  end

  defp validate_length(address_length) when address_length < 32, do: true
  defp validate_length(_address_length), do: false

  defp emit_event(event_description), do: Demo.Events.EventEmitter.emit(event_description)
end
```

Taken from [here](https://medium.com/onfido-tech/the-not-so-magic-tricks-of-testing-in-elixir-1-2-89bfcf252321)

I can see examples all over the web where a module defines a `@callback` and then another module implements the functions using `@behaviour` and `@impl`, but I'm not clear on what's happening when the `@callback` and the implementation are in the same module. What's the intention?

Comment: I too am baffled by this: the `validation_level/0` and other functions are not explicitly implementing anything, so AFAIK so they are not formally correlated to the `@callback`s.  More commonly, I have seen behaviour modules define `@callback`s and then define the `__using__` macro (via `defmacro`) so that any module that uses the behaviour module can "inherit" default implementations of the req'd functions -- `defoverridable` is handy here for achieving an OO-like feel.

Comment: Looks like the author either misunderstood what `@callback` is for, or something got lost when converting to demo code for their Medium post.

Comment: Another scenario for defining both a `@callback` and a concrete function in the same module is to help the "derived" module easily implement the `@callback`. (e.g. `Supervisor.init`, though the callback and the function have different arity)

Comment: I do this all the time in conjunction with `mox` - it builds mocks based on the callbacks of a behaviour. But in simple cases where I have just one module that would implement a behaviour, I just switch out the `@spec` to `@callback` and that module becomes both the behaviour and its implementation.